# API for iTunes upload via TeamCity

Tags: teamcity, app-store-connect

I am using TeamCity 9.01 as my continuous integration server. I am planning to have a build step to upload an .ipa file to iTunes. How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Changed the question to not have a focus on "is this possible" but instead to produce an actual result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [nomad-cli](http://nomad-cli.com) tools, specifically [Shenzhen](https://github.com/nomad/Shenzhen).

https://github.com/nomad/Shenzhen#itunes-connect-distribution

Comment: Morujao:  The answer seems to be a promising one.Can you please make it more clear

Comment: I think the website is pretty clear. Just check out the "iTunes Connect Distribution" section. Just install it and run with something like: ipa distribute:itunesconnect -a me@email.com -p myitunesconnectpassword -i appleid --upload